# knife winrm exists on TeamCity agent but gives me 'Cannot find sub command for: winrm..'

Tags: chef-infra, teamcity, knife

I am running a build via TeamCity to add a user to local admin group in windows server 2008, I SSH to the TeamCity build agent and run:

```
gem list | grep -i window
knife-windows (1.6.0, 1.5.0)
```

and

```
gem list | grep -i winrm
winrm (2.0.0, 1.8.1)
winrm-elevated (1.0.1)
winrm-fs (1.0.0)
```

As you see, knife-windows and winrm exist, so I can successfully run my command locally on the TC agent and user gets added/removed to/from local admin on Windows Server 2008.
But when I run the command via TeamCity, the build breaks with error:

```
Cannot find sub command for: 'winrm..'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: TeamCity agent keep the same configuration until it has been restarted, so he doesn't see everything which is freshly installed.

Comment: I have rebooted the agent, still having same error

Comment: Could be the account that TeamCity agent is running under? Have you tried the gem list commands as a step inside TeamCity? What do they output? Also, you have said what actual command you are trying in TeamCity, could it be escaping or other issue?